# Can't set UINavigationItem title programmatically

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem, uistoryboard

I set up my app using a storyboard and have my main view controller embedded in a `UINavigationControler`.  To change the title that appears in the navigation bar, in the `viewDidLoad` method of my main view controller, I have `self.navigationItem.title = @"My Title";` But the title never gets set.

My guess is that I need to set up a Reference Outlet in my storyboard, but I'm not sure what needs to be connected to what.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in story board, it doesn't get automatically connected , make a UINavigationItem using the following code in ur .h file

```
@property(weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationItem *navBar;
```

in .m file synthesize the property and set the title like this

```
@synthesize navBar;
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[self.navBar setTitle:@"Sign In"];
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
}
```

Also, don't forget to connect the UINavigationItem "navBar" in the storyBoard with ur class so that storyboard knows whose title to change. In case u don't have a UINavigationItem in ur storyboard,add it outside the UIView and then connect it properly

Answer (score 3):

Just setting the title property of the view controller you are in should do the trick.

```
[self setTitle:@"Best Page Ever"];
```

Comment: Hmm, have you tried setting the title before pushing the controller?

Answer (score 0):

After you have allocated your rootview..use:-

```
YourRootView *rootView=[YourRootView alloc]init];
rootView.title=@"yourTitle";
```

and then initialize it in uinavigationcontroller.(I don't have idea if you have your view on storyboard , then set its title just after allocating and then pass it as parameter to navigationcontroller).